# Python 3.9 - On taking numbers as input, min of input array returns empty value whereas max of array returns the correct value

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, input

**Problem statement** - Take 3 numbers as input array ***(without using map function)*** and print the min and max values in the array

**My solution-**

```
arr = input("Enter numbers ") #1 2 3
print(min(arr)) #returns empty
print(max(arr)) #returns 3
```

**Question-**
Why does max(arr) return the correct output and min(Arr) return an empty string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `input` returns a string and not an array of numbers. You'd have to split the numbers into a list and convert them to integers before you can calculate which is the minimum and which is the maximum:

```
arr = list(map(int, input("Enter numbers ").split(" ")))
print(min(arr))
print(max(arr))
```

Or if you'd like to avoid the map function, you can do it like this:

```
arr = []
for num_str in input("Enter numbers ").split(" "):
    arr.append(int(num_str))
print(min(arr))
print(max(arr))
```

`min` and `max` receive a list of objects as input and return the lowest/highest object in the list, respectively.

When you pass the string `"1 2 3"` to the `min` function the `min` function treats that string as a list of characters: `['1', ' ', '2', ' ', '3']`. The character `" "` is considered lower than `"1"` `"2"` and `"3"` so it's returned by `min`.

When you pass the string `"1 2 3"` to the `max` function the `max` function treats that string as a list of characters: `['1', ' ', '2', ' ', '3']`. The character `"3"` is considered higher than `"1"` `"2"` and `" "` so it was returned by `max`.